# Water seeping through my foundation in the garage - what is the source?

Tags: water, leak, foundation, waterproofing

I have a house built 1994, one story, slab foundation.

A few weeks back my renter left the sprinkler system on for over 7 hours on one side of the house (valve was broken).  By the time she called and we got the water shut down it was too late.  One side of the house was saturated already.  Now we have noticed water seeping into the garage and the master closet (sharing one wall) from the ground.

A plumber thinks it is water leak from a broken pipe.
I think it is from all the sprinkler system that was running for hours.

Would someone please tell me what I should do, the plumber wants over $2800 to cut the foundation and fix a pipe he does not know if it is broken or not.  Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to wait and see if the water continues to come in after a few days. It is quite possible that the sprinkler water is seeping through above the slab.
Are there bathrooms or other water usage utilities above where the leak is? Pipes usually rise vertically from the ground to the bathroom.
You could also try to shut off the main water valve for as long as possible to see if the water ingres shows down. Switch off water heaters before you do this.
You need to adjust the sprinkler heads so that they are not spraying on the house.

Answer (score 0):

If there really is a leak, it's easy to figure out. Make sure nothing in the house is actively using water (sink taps closed, no toilets running, etc.) and look at the water meter. If it's not absolutely, completely still, then you have a leak.